# Heatmap doesn't render the same as map layout

Tags: qgis, export, layouts, rendering

Im trying out a heatmap using QGIS. It looks good on the layout manager but when I export it the hotspots render a lot smaller on the map. I played around with the export settings, layer settings, symbology settings but still can't figure it out.

The first image is the export and the second image is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the scale is set to a high value that makes the view to look smaller. You need to adjust the scale to a smaller value to zoom in to the desired location. Also, you can fix the scale in order to fix the view of the layout to prevent it from being changed.

To do that:

- Go to the scale in the layout
- Click on Data defined override button

[image]

- Enter a value (only numbers) that focuses on the target area such as 50000, for example
- the Data defined override button will become yellow after entering a value

[image]

- This value will prevent the layout from being changed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've changed the "Radius" unit from a DPI-independent setting like "millimeters" or "map units" to "pixels". The sizes look good on a low-resolution screen, but are too small in a high-resolution layout export.